# How to implement some action when data changes in sqlite?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to implement some action in python (Django) whenever data changes in the sqlite db.
There are different sources by which data enters.

As of now the plan is to keep monitoring the db on a thread for every 2 mins.

I would like to know if there are better ways to implement, some callback type whenever data changes in the db ?

Comment: Does it change only in python code?

Comment: What do you mean by different sources? Are there other applications inserting data into the database or is it only django?

Comment: Another application will be inserting data

Answer (score 2):

You can use Django's [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save) signal for this job.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # fields

# connect a receiver 
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def do_some_action(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    do_that_action(instance)
```

Every time a `MyModel` object is saved, `do_some_action` function will be called.

See: [Django docs about signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/).